# Select DISTINCT from MYSQL database

Tags: java, mysql, distinct

I need to extract some data from my database, but the problem is that Im getting repeated values from the database, which I do not want.

The username is stored into the database multiple times.

I tried using DISTINCT but it did not work.

Can anyone tell me how to extract the username from the database only once?

Code:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect
            .prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT username, score, name from score order by score desc limit 10");
```

Comment: Is it only the `username` thats repeated or also the `score` and `name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` instead of `distinct`.  `Select distinct` applies to all columns being selected:

```
SELECT username, max(score) as score, max(name) as name
from score
group by username
order by score desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks! BTW, what does "max(score) as score" mean?

Comment: That means to take the maximum value of `score` for each `username` and assign it the name of `score` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the score and name from your query.